# Media query difference screen size in one css stylesheet

Tags: css

Hello I have this script and I need when screen size is 1600 px `background-color`  was red and when screen size is 1366 px `background-color` was black, but my code not work, media query works only 1600 px

html

```
<div>

</div>
```

css

```
div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:grey;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1366px){
    div{
        background-color:black;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1600px){
    div{
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second styles overwrite the first one. Change the order. It will work.

```
 div{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:grey;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1600px){
   div
   {
    background-color:red;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1366px){
   div
   {
    background-color:black;
   }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cqyLhxd3/)